# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Tags: laravel

```
    $video_file = Input::file('video_file');
    $original_name = $video_file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

Not sure why but the second line is giving me an error.

This is my form:

```
    <li>
        {{Form::label('video_title', 'Title')}}
        {{Form::text('video_title')}}


    </li>
    <li>
        {{Form::label('video_body', 'Body')}}
        {{Form::textarea('video_body')}}


    </li>
    <li>
        {{Form::label('video_file', 'Choose a video')}}
        {{Form::file('video_file')}}

    </li>
    <li>
        {{Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'primary-btn'))}}
        {{Form::close()}}
    </li>
```

My form seems to be working fine it's obviously has something to do with the object the method getClientOriginalName() is called upon. I tried without the [0], but I am getting the same thing.

```
POST Data
_token  F3TJRaqVy9kRDbFyLqrue0mfpNvUzQjRr0Um6GjW
video_title     gfffffffffff
video_body  gfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgf
video_file  01 - Introduction.mp4
```

I set my upload size and post size to 400M in my PHP.ini file and I think it should work. Do I need to upload a package or something? I thought the method was native to vanilla PHP.

Comment: Try `dd($video_file)` to see what is in the variable and if the file is making its way to the server. Also try doing `$files = Input::file();` and see if there are any files submitted at all.

Comment: Thanks for responding, will the output appear in the console or on the error page?

Comment: Wait, I am getting null. Why is that? It says video_file 01 - Introduction.mp4 in the POST Data.

Comment: I then tried to upload a 124kb flv video and I am still getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`￼￼{{Form::file('video_file')}}` isn't declared as an array (eg: `{{Form::file('video_file[]')}}`) so you'll have to access it as `$video_file->getClientOriginalName();` without the `[0]`.

**UPDATE**

Make sure you open your form with `files` set to `true`.
`Form::open([...'files' => true ])`

Comment: getting the same thing:Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Comment: Did you open your form with the `files` option set to `true`? `Form::open([...'files' => true])`

Comment: ohh that was the problem.